# Discord.py Auto-assigned Roles

Tags: bots, discord, discord.py

I have been looking over this bit for a few hours now and I can't seem to put my hands on it, I'm trying to create a bot that's sole purpose is replacing roles on during a sepcific time frame of my choice.
To understand it more, the server is a learning one designed for my school, what I want is to enter quiz times, during these times students are listed on a role that puts them all on mute to avoid cheating, etc..
I was hoping someone here had an idea or two...

Comment: Can you show code of what you tried so far?

Comment: That's a point, I have snippets of everything bas can't figure out how to put everything together..

Comment: Hi @AhmedM.Gamal! We need some code to be able to understand what you are trying to do